# validation if there is any error is present in form then can not go to next page in react

Tags: reactjs

In my form if i enter numbers rather than  text and it will give an error then after clicking on next button it should not be redirected to next page.
how to prevent this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clicking on the next button will execute a validation function, and based on the result, you will decide whether to navigate to the other page or display an error and stay on the same page.

Even better (and assuming that you have multiple fields in the form): check the value of every field when the user leaves the field (onBlur) and notify the user about the error immediately then. This is not instead of running validation on 'Next' or on 'Submit', since the user may click on the button without visiting that field.

Long time ago (as a test for me, during my study of react), I created a small project that implements a form. It is far from perfect, but you might find it useful: https://github.com/rahamin1/reactstrap-form